# Windows Service: How to load balance the requests

Tags: c#, windows-services, load-balancing

My current solution looks like this:
On my computer I have a windows service that holds a persistent connenction to Microsoft Dynamics.
Using a Service Reference, my client software calls the service and sends a request to Microsoft Dynamics.

That works fine.

What I need to do is:

- a service (or many services) that holds 10 persistent connections to Microsoft Dynamics
- load balanced access to the connections from many clients, so the requests can be handled parallel

Do you have any suggestions, how this is realizable?
Everything should be programmed in C#.

//edit:

http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/

I use this service and added the connection-stuff I found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2007/07/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-4-0-from-net-using-the-dynamics-ax-net-business-connector.aspx

Comment: Persistent connection to dynamics?? And how is built your service? By design a windows service with a WCF host can accept concurrent connection. Please clarify

Comment: I edited the question.
The service is logged in to the Dynamics system the whole time.